# Android - Get Data From MySql Database Using Inner Join (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, android, mysql, codeigniter

I want to get data from android to my server that have made ​​with CodeIgniter framework. But I have problems when I want to take the "marker" data by performing inner join on mysql database. But on android, it always get the `result==false`.

It's my android source code

```
protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean result) {
        dialog.cancel();
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (result == false) {
                    showInfo();
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < array.size(); i++) {
                        HashMap<String, String> newMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        newMap = array.get(i);
                        mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(newMap.get("nama"), newMap.get("deskripsi"), newMap.get("foto"), newMap.get("marker"), Double.parseDouble(newMap.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble(newMap.get("lng"))));
                    }
                    plotMarkers(mMyMarkersArray);
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Codeigniter (controller) source code

```
public function getContentLocation(){
    $response=array();
    $result = $this->m_krb->getAllContent();
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        $response["konten"] = array();

        foreach($result->result() as $row):
            $pendaftaran = array();
            $pendaftaran["id"] = $row->id_table_petakrb;
            $pendaftaran["nama"] = $row->nama_petakrb;
            $pendaftaran["deskripsi"] = $row->deskripsi;
            $pendaftaran["foto"]='http://192.168.43.137/navigasikrb/assets/img/foto/'.$row->foto;
            $icon = $row->marker_icon;
            $marker = $this->m_krb->checkGroup($icon)->result();
            $pendaftaran["marker"] = $marker->nama_group;
            $pendaftaran["lng"] = $row->longitude;
            $pendaftaran["lat"] = $row->latitude;
            array_push($response["konten"], $pendaftaran);
        endforeach;

    // sukses
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echo JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Tidak ada data yang ditemukan";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

Codeigniter (model) source code

```
    function getAllContent(){
       $query=$this->db->query("select * from table_petakrb ");
       return $query;
    }

    function checkGroup($icon){
       $query=$this->db->query("select table_group.nama_group FROM table_group INNER JOIN table_petakrb ON table_petakrb.marker_icon = table_group.file_icon WHERE table_petakrb.marker_icon = '$icon'  ");
       return $query;
    }
```

But if i change the codeigniter controller source code like this, it can get the data sucessfully on android.

```
public function getContentLocation(){
    $response=array();
    $result = $this->m_krb->getAllContent();
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        $response["konten"] = array();

        foreach($result->result() as $row):
            $pendaftaran = array();
            $pendaftaran["id"] = $row->id_table_petakrb;
            $pendaftaran["nama"] = $row->nama_petakrb;
            $pendaftaran["deskripsi"] = $row->deskripsi;
            $pendaftaran["foto"]='http://192.168.43.137/navigasikrb/assets/img/foto/'.$row->foto;
            $pendaftaran["marker"] = $row->marker_icon;
            $pendaftaran["lng"] = $row->longitude;
            $pendaftaran["lat"] = $row->latitude;
            array_push($response["konten"], $pendaftaran);
        endforeach;

    // sukses
    $response["success"] = 1;

    // echo JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Tidak ada data yang ditemukan";

        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
```

But the problem is i can't take the data with the inner join as I wrote the source code above. Is there something wrong with my code?